# Performance Hit While Routing Cable Internet Through Surge Protector?

Tags: power, cable, cable-modem, surge-protection

I recently purchased a Belkin surge protector with cable line protection. I have cable Internet, and that cord is plugged into my modem, which has an Ethernet going to my router where it splits and powers my entire network.

I was wondering whether it would be smart to plug in the cable line into the surge protector, and purchase some kind of patch cable to connect the surge protector to the modem.

However, I need to know if I need to buy a specific type of cable. Will there be performance hits if I route Internet traffic through a surge protector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Any** sort of connector will produce interference and degrade quality, however I doubt it will be anything significant, nor will it reduce your speed.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, yes. Especially for coax.

With a 200mbps cable internet plan, and a UPS/surge protector with both ethernet and coaxial protection, I saw dramatic performance drops with both.

For coax (wall -> surge protector -> modem), my top speed dropped to ~33mbps. SNR plummeted and I saw tons of errors ("Uncorrectables" in modem status page).

For ethernet (modem -> surge protector -> router), my top speed dropped to ~100mbps. A suspicious number, but I could find no specific mention of gigabit support (or not) on the UPS.